Canon EOS90D Auto-focus indicator light
I have a Canon EOS90D and would like the auto-focus indicator light to come on in all light conditions. Can anyone help with the required settings?

Do you mean the dot in viewfinder?

Hi Romeo, yes. I would like it to come on whenever the subject is in focus and not just in really low light

For me looks like you can't get focus in darkness. Any chance to use torch/flashlight to get the focus?

It seems the OP is asking for the autofocus assistance light (that will turn on when it's too dark) and not "the dot in viewfinder".
